# better idiom for the following flow

Tags: clojure

I have a piece of code as follows -

```
        (future
          (
            (comp
             (fn [data]
               (service/parse srv data))
             (fn []
               (service/fetch srv))
            )))
```

Basically there are two functions `fetch` and `parse` which I have to call in a future. The result of the `fetch` is used by the `parse` function. Somehow the above seems to verbose, as I have to create anonymous functions just so that I can `comp` them and then use an extra () to execute the comped function.

Any better ways of achieving the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(future
    (->> (service/fetch srv)
         (service/parse srv)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `srv` is some url or other object defined in a Var? Unclear from your code. Anyway, the equivalent:

```
(future
  (let [data (service/fetch srv)]
    (service/parse srv data)))
```

or simply

```
(future
  (service/parse srv (service/fetch srv)))
```

I expect you can refactor `parse` so it doesn't depend on `srv`, but I don't have enough info about your problem to be sure.